# How to easily deploy HTTPS in Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: ssl, apache-http-server, https, ssl-certificate

I have an Apache web server running on Ubuntu 10.04, and I would like to switch everything to HTTPS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache2 makes this very easy with the additional tools packaged with it. If you have the apache2-common package installed, you can enable the `mod_ssl` module (required for HTTPS) in one easy command:

```
sudo a2enmod ssl
```

Apache2 also includes a command to help you easily generate self-signed certificates called `apache2-ssl-certificate`. Generate your certificate for the server as shown below or use certificates purchased through a trusted root CA ( Verisign, Entrust, Thawte, etc ).

```
sudo apache2-ssl-certificate -days 365
```

Keep in mind, users will receive this infamous warning when viewing your site if you use a self-signed certificate:

[image]

Use the following 4 statements in your Apache configuration ( `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` ) or VirtualHost directive ( below `DocumentRoot` ) to turn on the SSL Engine for that particular site:

```
SSLEngine on
SSLOptions +StrictRequire
SSLCertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl/certs/apache.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/apache-ssl/apache.pem
```

The `SSLOptions +StrictRequire` forces SSL communication only for that particular site. The `SSLCertificateFile` and `SSLCertificateKeyFile` specify the locations to your SSL certificate and it's corresponding key.

Ensure we are listening on port 443 by modifying `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` to include the `Listen` directive:

```
echo "Listen 443" >> /etc/apache2/ports.conf
```

Finally you must restart Apache2 to initiate the changes:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

**Additional Fun**:

Configure HTTP requests on port 80 to [**redirect to port 443**](http://www.whoopis.com/howtos/apache-rewrite.html) with `mod_rewrite`.

**Note**:

Some of this data is from past experience with Debian/Ubuntu systems, for the most accurate instructions there is a guide for 10.04 on [**the Ubuntu website**](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/httpd.html).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not telling you *how* to do this, it's beyond the scope of this forum IMO<sup>**(1)**</sup>. I'm only saying *what* I think you can do.

There really isn't an *easy* way to do this. You really have to know a bit about apache configuration and dig down in the configuration files. In addition to that you need a [SSL certificate](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=what%20is%20a%20https%20certificate)

The easiest way would be to tell your web server to stop listening to port 80<sup>**(2)**</sup> and only listen to port 443. A better solution would be to have apache [redirect all connections to port 80 to port 443](http://www.whoopis.com/howtos/apache-rewrite.html)

<sub><sup>(1)</sup> And beyond my expertise</sub>
<sub><sup>(2)</sup> Or block port 80 in your firewall</sub>

Comment: I just noticed I stole the same link as you for mod_rewrite. Have a +1 :)